# Send mail after git commit not push

Tags: git, githooks

I need to send email with diff after commit to the repository. I know how to send emails after push, but it is not working for commits.

For pushes I've created hook post-receive that gets parameters   . But the hook post-commit does not recieve any parameters and because of that I can't use my script that sends mail.

Maybe there is a way to get info about newrev and refname in post-commit hook, or there is some other way to send mail after commit?

Comment: Are those hooks on the server ("origin" repository)? If so, do you want to have a commit-hook also on the server (is anyone committing there directly?), or on your client machine? In the usual setup, a "push" is what would be a "commit" in the "traditional" (svn) sense. Git commits are local events, not necessarily being shared with anyone.

Comment: No, there is no other repository to push to. If there was I didn't asked this question =)

Answer (score 7):

The answer is simple =) I've solved my issue by creating post-commit hook with this line:

```
git log -1 -p|mail -s "Git commit" mail@example.com
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work, mail returned `send-mail: invalid option -- 's'`. Turns out on new mail versions it is now required to place your address after the -s (subject) switch like so `git log -1 -p|mail -s "Git commit" mail@example.com`